Is this definite integral solveable?
I was doing a physics problem and the final answer was a vector field given by 3 rather unsightly integrals. Since my issue is mathematical, I figured I should post it here as opposed to the Physics Stack Exchange.
The vector field B is given by:
$$\vec{B}(x,y,z)=P(x,y,z)\hat{x}+Q(x,y,z)\hat{y}+R(x,y,z)\hat{z}$$
Where
$$P(x,y,z)=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{z\cos(t)}{(R^2+x^2+y^2+z^2-2xR\cos(t)-2yR\sin(t))^{3/2}}dt$$
$$Q(x,y,z)=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{z\sin(t)}{(R^2+x^2+y^2+z^2-2xR\cos(t)-2yR\sin(t))^{3/2}}dt$$
$$R(x,y,z)=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{R-x\cos(t)-y\sin(t)}{(R^2+x^2+y^2+z^2-2xR\cos(t)-2yR\sin(t))^{3/2}}dt$$
Where R, x, y, and z are independent of t.
I was able to have MatLab model the vector field, but I was still wondering if there was any way to actually evaluate the integrals. I tried basically every method of integration that I know (which admittedly isn't a ton; I'm only in multivariable). I even tried Feynman's trick, but no luck. If anyone could help me, or even confirm that it is impossible, it would be greatly appreciated.
If anyone is wondering, the vector field gives the resultant magnetic field (barring some physical constants that I left out of this question) of a circular current of radius R at any point (x,y,z) where (0,0,0) is at the center of said circle.

According to Maple, these are elliptic integrals.  They are evaluated in terms of $E$ and $F$.
